# Pydicom - can't read pixel_array after assigning PixelData

Tags: pydicom

Trying to downsize a dicom image follwing the example provided at [pydicom](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/dev/auto_examples/image_processing/plot_downsize_image.html). However,when then trying to access ds.pixel_array I get the error: Unexpected tag '(3fff, 3fff)' when parsing the Basic Table Offset item.

This error also happens when directly assigning the original ds.pixel_array to ds.PixelData, like this:

```
ds = pydicom.dcmread(f)
data = ds.pixel_array 
print(data.shape)
ds.PixelData = data.tobytes()
print(ds.pixel_array.shape)
```

I also get Unexpected tag '(3fff, 3fff)' when parsing the Basic Table Offset item.

I suppose something is corrupted in the original dicom file but I don't know what ds tag value I should change to be able to read de pixel_array after assigning PixelData.

Comment: If you work with compressed data, you cannot just assign the `pixel_data` array to `PixelData` - you have to recompress it first. So far, pydicom does [not directly support this](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/dev/tutorials/pixel_data/compressing.html). Alternatively, you have to change the transfer syntax and possibly other tags to save the data uncompressed.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I finally solved the issue by doing:
ds.file_meta.TransferSyntaxUID = pydicom.uid.ExplicitVRLittleEndian